# typescript: create interface for cryptocompare coinlist API

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to make a TypeScript interface for the cryptocompare coinlist API (https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/data/coinlist/)

I have currently tried this:

```
interface CoinListResponse {
    Response: string,
    Message: string,
    BaseImageUrl: string,
    BaseLinkUrl: string,
    Type: number,
    Data: Array<Coin>
}
```

Now, that part works but there is a problem with `Data: Array<Coin>`, because `Data` isn't an array but an object. You can see the documenation here: https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/#-api-data-coinlist-

This is what I want to resolve:
[image: example code]

This is the Coin interface:

```
export interface Coin {
    Id: number,
    Url: string,
    Name: string,
    CoinName: string,
    FullName: string,
    Algorithm: string,
    ProofType: string,
    SortOrder: number
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: but.. data doesnt have sortOrder either.I think it would be another object inside data.And is there a reason you are returning `Observable<Coin[]>` as you are not dealing with array?

Comment: @SurajRao I want to use as an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the API JSON response definition:

```
    "Data": {
        "LTC": {
            "Id": "3808",
            "Url": "/coins/ltc/overview",
            "ImageUrl": "/media/19782/ltc.png",
            "Name": "LTC",
            "CoinName": "Litecoin",
            "FullName": "Litecoin (LTC)",
            "Algorithm": "Scrypt",
            "ProofType": "PoW",
            "SortOrder": "2"
        }
        ...
    },
```

The `Data` property can be modeled as a key-value pair type, where the key is the currency name (`string`) and the value is of type `Coin`.

```
export interface CoinData {
  [key: string]: Coin
};

interface CoinListResponse {
    Response: string,
    Message: string,
    BaseImageUrl: string,
    BaseLinkUrl: string,
    Type: number,
    Data: CoinData
}
```

Comment: Hmm. that's one step closer but now I get `[ts] Operator '<=' cannot be applied to types 'Coin' and 'number'.`

Comment: That's because you have to access the specific currency by name: `coin['LTC'].SortOrder`. Otherwise you're accessing the whole hash-set, which contains multiple currencies and their data.

Comment: Thank you. I wanted it to be iterable. see my answe below.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for `[ts] Operator '<=' cannot be applied to types 'Coin' and 'number'.`

```
export function coins$(): Observable<any> {
    const response = WebRequest.json<CoinListResponse>(`${API_BASE}/data/all/coinlist`);
    return Observable.fromPromise(response)
        .map(response => response.Data)
        .map(coins => Object.values(coins).filter(coin => coin.SortOrder <= COIN_LIMIT));
};
```